# How to validate model bound form using jquery on ajax post?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using an mvc form with model bound field which have required tags.

but submitting them using ajax post by serializing the form.

Now the validation messages doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm)
```

Instead of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm
```

And also add -

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailOrContactField, "", new { @class = "text-danger error-msg" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add the @html.validationmessagefor for each model item in the view page?